# Landing pages management

Tags: development, article-manager, server

I have a dedicated share Ip with multiple cpanels, and multiple domain names.

Where I work we have about 20 different products that we promote in different landing pages, currently each landing page is a wordpress site with their own unique domain. I want to change this to have everything in one place and with Joomla. This way I can have only ideally 1 installation and 20 pages (1 per landing page).

I have follow the instructions on Multiple Domains and Web Sites in a single Joomla! installation https://docs.joomla.org/Multiple_Domains_and_Web_Sites_in_a_single_Joomla!_installation  in order to manage the redirects, however this doesnt explain how to manage the directory.

WHat I have done is I have 20 cpanels and in each I have install Joomla and modify the config.php to connect to the same database, however each installation of joomla still feeds from their own directory and i want to be feed from the master directory (the original joomla site with the website that has the 20 pages).

Is there a way to achieve this or I am approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting from 20 independent Cpanels. Then, you are trying to connect to the same database and load a site for each Cpanel from a single folder. Mainly, you are going against Cpanel design principles of hosting.

The article **Multiple Domains and Web Sites in a single Joomla! installation** assumes multiple domains *in the same* Cpanel. Plus, you only have to administer a single site.

You can host any number of domains on a Cpanel, only restricted by available resources. In your hosting, you can configure a redirect www.my-product.com to a specific page www.my-product.com/landing1.html. From Joomla side, you have to associate landing1 template with a specific landing1 alias in a menu item. Redirects can be managed in Cpanel or with a Joomla extension (like Joomla redirection or Akeeba AdminTools).